# How to write coverage test case for wxpython's event.Skip()?

Tags: wxpython, attributeerror, coverage.py

I am trying to increase my coverage percentage on my coverage report and there is this method that I want to write a test case for using an **assert ** statement. It is only one line, but for my test case no matter what I pass in as "event", I get an AttributeError. For example if my test case is

```
`assert DPrintSettings.Dialog1.OnCPrinterChoice("test", new_tree) == None`
```

From this statement I get the message: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'Skip'`

Here is the actual method:

```
def OnCPrinterChoice(self, event):
        event.Skip()
```

What type of input do I need to pass through my test case for this error to be resolved?

I tried passing through different types of parameters like a string, integer, float, lists, etc. but keep getting the same AttributeError because none of those have the "Skip" attribute. I am not sure what to pass in as an "event" that has a "Skip" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a wx.EVENT using  `wx.lib.newevent`

```
>>> import wx.lib.newevent
>>> MyEvent, EVT_MY_TEST = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
>>> dir(MyEvent)
['ClassInfo', 'ClassName', 'Clone', 'Destroy', 'EventObject', 'EventType', 'GetClassInfo', 'GetClassName', 'GetEventCategory', 'GetEventObject', 'GetEventType', 'GetId', 'GetRefData', 'GetSkipped', 'GetTimestamp', 'Id', 'IsCommandEvent', 'IsSameAs', 'Ref', 'RefData', 'ResumePropagation', 'SetEventObject', 'SetEventType', 'SetId', 'SetRefData', 'SetTimestamp', 'ShouldPropagate', 'Skip', 'Skipped', 'StopPropagation', 'Timestamp', 'UnRef', 'UnShare', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_getAttrDict']
>>>
```